# OP's name isn't highlighted in several places in iPad app

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, ios-app, ipad

The user Konstantinos Gaitanas is the OP of the question, yet their first two comments are not highlighted, even though the third one is.

[image: Screenshot of iPad app]

I am using iPad 2 and the app version is 1.2.2.203.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a bug with the iOS app. [The question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/what-was-the-answer-to-this-paradox-before-cantor) in question was commented on by the OP before the migration and the user's status was shown appropriately.

> [image]

However, the question was then migrated and even though the OP's accounts [*are* linked](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/users/2056/konstantinos-gaitanas), the comments were not updated to link to the correct account. This is shown by both Eric and Konstantinos not having links to their profile.

> [image]

According to the iOS app, even though the user has the same name, the user who commented isn't the OP, therefore showing the background on the user's name is incorrect.

Comment: Yep, this seems to be a migration bug...

Comment: Should we have the message bar announces that the question is migrated?

Comment: wait a minute. Why is Todd Trimble's name in the third comment clickable? Didn't he comment before the migration?

Comment: @Ooker just cuz he has an account in hsm. If anyone creates an account in the target migration site, their content gets linked, also.

Comment: So when the op commented after the migration, his account was created and linked to the old one too?

Comment: Marking as [tag:status-bydesign] for the reason in this answer.  That said, I'm also going to make names in comments like this the same color as comment text to indicate that they are not links.